# Find the volume of the given solid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, volume

Find the volume of the solid
$$\{(x,y,z) : x ≥0,y ≥0,z ≥0,z ≤2 −e^y, x + y + z ≤10\}.$$

Not sure if my workings for this is correct? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[workings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGGSP.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: No, your work is not correct. Note that $0\leq z \leq 2 −e^y$ implies that $y\leq ln(2)$. As regards $z$, we have that $0\leq z\leq \min(2-e^y,10-x-y)$.

Comment: @RobertZ thanks! So I'll have to split the integral into 2 parts? One where z goes from 0 to 2-e^y and other where z goes from 0 to 10-x-y

Comment: You can get away with one triple integral if you integrate in the order $dx\,dy\,dz$.